# how to count total left and total right child of a user in downline in a MLM binary Tree in SQL CTE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I am facing some of problem while getting the following result from a parent child relationship please check the follwing table structure.
[image]

The above is the table structure and the tree structure is like below image.
[image]

in case of my scenario here is an MLM tree  in which every person have down line members on left side and right side.so i need to calculate this for the current login user in their down line

So i need the right side summary recursively  thanks in advance

```
    ALTER Function [dbo].[F_SearchUsersTreeByParent](@id as int)
Returns table as 
Return


WITH CTE_Table (id, FullName,UserName, RefferdByID,Levels,LevelPrice, IsPurchasedProduct)
AS
(
SELECT id, FullName,UserName,-1 as RefferdByID,Levels,LevelPrice,IsPurchasedProduct
FROM Registration WHERE id = @id and Registration.IsPurchasedProduct=1
UNION ALL
SELECT Registration.id, Registration.FullName,Registration.UserName, Registration.RefferdByID,Registration.Levels,Registration.LevelPrice, Registration.IsPurchasedProduct FROM Registration
JOIN CTE_Table ON Registration.RefferdByID = CTE_Table.id
where Registration.IsPurchasedProduct=1
)

SELECT id, FullName,UserName, RefferdByID,Levels,LevelPrice, IsPurchasedProduct,

(Select count(*)-1 from dbo.F_CountRefered(id) where id<>abc.id) as RefCount
 FROM CTE_Table as abc
```

Comment: You have to make an algorithm within a while loop/s to be able to build such a tree. It wont be hard with good indentation and comments but its time consuming.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback and i dont need to display the tree i have done that already with common table expression in sql now i need to count the summary with CTE ie to create a CTE function that will calculate left and right nodes recursively in downline.

Comment: you can see the summary information on right side of  the tree

Comment: Can you show that CTE, maybe it can be done with it?

Comment: How do you get for SFSINT : 4 LEFT and 3 RIGHT ?

Comment: i have just write this actaully the right side summary data is not coming from database this is what i want to get throug sql store procedure

Comment: loot the CTE thou which i am display downline member for a particular user recursively.

Answer (score 0):

```
$memid="95000";   // your id

function getTotalLeg($memid,$leg){ 
      global $conn;
     $sql="select child_class from tree_class where parent_id='".$memid."' and position='".$leg."'";
      $res=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
      $row=mysqli_fetch_array($res);
      global $total;
       $total=$total+mysqli_num_rows($res);
         if($row['child_class']!=''){
           getTotalLeg ($row['child_class'],'L');
           getTotalLeg ($row['child_class'],'R');
          } 
          return $total;      
        }      

     $total=0; 
    $left=getTotalLeg($memid,"L");    
    echo $total."</br>"; 
     $total=0;
    $right=getTotalLeg($memid,"R");  
    echo $total;
```